# In swift, why can I set a computed property of a polymorphic variable via optional chaining, but not on an unwrapped optional?

Tags: swift

I ran into what I think is a strange error in may app.  At the bottom of this question is complete code the reproduces what I am seeing in my app, but here is a quick demonstration.

---

I create two instances of the same class,  one is declared as an optional conforming to a protocol the other as an optional of a concrete class

For both I can set the computed property via option chaining ie:

```
anOptionalInstance?.someComputedProperty = ....
```

for the concrete version I can set the property by unwrapping the optional

```
if let anInstance = anOptionalInstance {
  anInstance.someComputedProperty = ....
}
```

For the polymorphic version, I get an error message that says I can't set  the property on the instance.

---

Below is a complete file that reproduces the issue I am seeing.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
struct MyStruct {
  var someMember: String
}

protocol MyProtocol {
  var myVar: MyStruct { get set }
}

class MyType: MyProtocol {
  var myVar: MyStruct {
    get {
      return MyStruct(someMember: "some string")
    }
    set {
      println(newValue)
    }
  }
}


class UsingClass {
  var anInstanceOfMyType: MyProtocol?
  var anOtherInstanceOfMyType: MyType?

  func someMethod() {

    anInstanceOfMyType = MyType()
    anInstanceOfMyType?.myVar = MyStruct(someMember: "blah")
    if let anInstanceOfMyType = anInstanceOfMyType {
       // The following line produces this error :Cannot assign to 'myVar' in 'anInstanceOfMyType'
      anInstanceOfMyType.myVar = MyStruct(someMember: "blah blah")
    }

    anOtherInstanceOfMyType = MyType()
    anOtherInstanceOfMyType?.myVar = MyStruct(someMember: "blah")
    if let anOtherInstanceOfMyType = anOtherInstanceOfMyType {
      anOtherInstanceOfMyType.myVar = MyStruct(someMember: "blah blah")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does happen because you are trying to change the property of the **constant** `anInstanceOfMyType` which type is `MyProtocol`.

### 1. Why `anInstanceOfMyType` is a constant?

At the first line of `UsingClass`, `anInstanceOfMyType` is actually declared as `var`. However with the `Conditional Unwrapping` a constant with name `anInstanceOfMyType` is created, and you are trying to change a property of that constant

### 2. Ok but `anInstanceOfMyType` references an instance of a class, so I should be able to change its properties even if it's a constant

Since `anInstanceOfMyType` has `MyProtocol` as type, it could contain a `struct` or a reference an `instance of a class`.
So the compiler does apply the safer approach and avoid you to change its properties.

### Solution

Limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or enumerations) by adding the class keyword to a protocol’s inheritance list. The class keyword must always appear first in a protocol’s inheritance list, before any inherited protocols:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
  var myVar: MyStruct { get set }
}
```

or

If `MyProtocol` is updated to extend `AnyObject`

```
protocol MyProtocol : AnyObject {
    var myVar: MyStruct { get set }
}
```

then becomes clear that `anInstanceOfMyType` must refer an instance of a class, in this case your code does compile.

Comment: I think am am still confused,  anInstanceOfMyType is an instance of a class (reference type), not a struct (value type), so I _think_ let _should_ work as I am not changing the reference, and let does work for the concrete case.  The property, myVar that I am setting is a struct however.  Another way of phrasing my confusion is: Then, why don't I need var for the concrete case?

Comment: Good point. I needed to look at the official documentation to answer to this comment. I think the idea is that the type of `anInstanceOfMyType` is `MyProtocol`. So for the compiler this variable could contains an instance of a class or a struct. Then the compiler allows you to change a property of a **variable** of type `MyProtocol`. BUT it does not allo you to change the property of a **constant** of type `MyProtocol`.

Comment: ah, I think that's it ... i need to say the protocol can only be classes

Comment: Correct. Infact if `MyProtocol` extends `AnyObject` your original does code compile.

Comment: actually just define it as protocol MyProtocol: class {

Comment: Ok. Please remember to accept my answer if you think it is correct.

Comment: actually I was going to suggest you consider fixing it up a bit so I could accept it.  I think we both understand what is going on now, but as it stands the answer does not really explain what is happening. In fact the suggestion of using var in place of let actually would introduce a nasty bug if both classes and structs were used, which you elude to in  your comment section.  (classes would work as intended - the property in the reference would be changed, structs would be broken - the property in a copy would be changed)

Comment: Right, I updated my answer. Let me know if you think it's fine now.